# Postgres JDBC Error: Received resultset tuples, but no field structure for them

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-data

We are using Postgres in a Java Spring application:

**Postgres Version: 10**

**Postgres JDBC Dependency Version: 42.1.4**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

There is a random error in the same deployed code that can't be replicated in other environments; the error goes away on restarting the application. It seems to occur on a Select when authenticating a user.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received resultset tuples, but no field structure for them
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2121)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor126.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
```

The closest I could find was this thread, but I don't understand the solution or whether it's available in any new versions. Is it a Postgres JDBC bug?
http://www.pgpool.net/mantisbt/view.php?id=432

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What happens if you use the latest version of the driver: 42.2.5? Also what PostgreSQL version are you using?

Comment: We can't provide a "Complete and Verifiable example" because the error is sporadic/random. It went away after bouncing the app, and hasn't occurred since. All I have is the log entry from the period when it was occurring. We're using PostgreSQL 10. So we should upgrade to 42.2.5? We'll give that a try, but even if there's no further occurrence, it's a rare error, so hard to know for sure unless someone confirms 42.2.5 fixes it.

Comment: If you look at the changelog https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html occurrences of that error have been fixed in 4.2.0, so yes, upgrading will probably fix it. And even if it wasn't: upgrading dependencies is usually a good thing to do.

Comment: Some users experienced same error : https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/811

Comment: But in this thread, http://www.pgpool.net/mantisbt/view.php?id=432 , the fix was checked into Master on *2018-10-12* . That is later than the August 2018 release of the latest-to-date version 42.2.5 (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/), no? In other words, even the latest 42.2.5 still doesn't have the latest proposals from that thread I quoted?

Comment: Your current problem is with the JDBC driver, why are you looking at issues of a different tool and then conclude that it probably isn't fixed in the JDBC driver?! There is a fix listed in the changelog of the driver (see also the link posted by Govind Parashar), so you can assume it is fixed. The appropriate action is to upgrade and if the problem still occurs, to report it on the pgjdbc GitHub.

Comment: OK thanks. I didn't realize that one was about "pgpool" which is a different tool. I'll plug in the 42.2.5 JDBC.